# O que fazer com o token de autenticação quando este chega no front?

Tags: laravel, angular, api, aplicação-web

Estou desenvolvendo um site com o Laravel no server (API) e o angular no front. Para autenticar um usuário no sistema, eu recupero as credenciais (email e senha) e, caso o usuário exista e a senha esteja correta, eu retorno um token para o front (angular).

Quando esse token está no front, o que devo fazer com esse token? Armazeno em alguma variável?

Qualquer comentário que vc possa me fazer sobre isso já é de grande ajuda, mesmo que por cima. Pois já me ajuda a ter uma noção!

Comment: é seguinte com esse token podes armazenar como uma cookie no browser e sempre que o utilizador atualizar a pagina verificas se o token ja expirou se não existir essa cookie em especifico so informa que o utilizador não esta logado, apenas uma simples ideia...

Comment: Entendi. Mas além de armazená-lo como cookie no browser, eu posso armazená-lo em uma variável utilizando o angular, não é?

Comment: Sim claro que podes e deves